# What are the options for integrating a R linter in a text editors? lint in svTools, codetools etc

Tags: r, coding-style, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I am trying to extend SublimeLinter with a linter for R. SublimeLinter provides automatic linting in Sublime Text 2 for a lot of languages. The goal is that the linter runs in the background and highlights lines with coding errors or bad coding style.

Currently, I am using the `lint` function in the `svTools` package and it's working. The results, however, are not every satisfying. The linter catches to many `)` in a line or to many `}` but it doesn't detect the use of undefined variables, no coding style etc.

Are there any other options? I am aware of this discussion [Writing a R lint program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160150/writing-a-r-lint-program), `R CMD check`, and `codetools`. But how can I run `R CMD check` on a normal .r file and not a package? What options should be used for an on the fly linter? Any other ideas?

Thanks!

edit: the `lint` function also does not seem to be very good in detecting the location of the error or it basically always indicates column 1. For example, in `fn = function(...) { ]` the column is 1 not the `]` at the end.

ps: I know that the `lint` function is a wrapper for `checkUsage()`...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Andrew's (lint author) [github repository](https://github.com/halpo), in particular NppToR for ideas on the editor integration.

As for how to run R CMD check on a normal .r file you could create a package skeleton and use the R path as a cache for the currently edited file.  Obviously figuring out the best/required R CMD check options as you go; though it may be easier to read the source for how R CMD is doing what it does, as well as how some of the open source R IDEs make use of and parse the output (ie: RStudio and its' error reporting).